# Script in laravel stop working cause the @section('content')

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, web

That my code i have in a view a research bar and it works perfectly until i put @section and @section('content').

i try to remove it and just use the extend but doesnt work

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <head>
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Live Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3>Suche nach Telefonnummern </h3>
                    <div class="panel-heading"><a href="{{ url('home') }}">zurück zum Senden von Nachrichten</a></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-controller" id="search" name="search"></input>
        </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nummer</th>
                <th>Nachricht</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
        </div>
            </div>
                </div>
                

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#search').on('keyup',function(){
$value=$(this).val();
$.ajax({
type : 'get',
url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
data:{'search':$value},
success:function(data){
$('tbody').html(data);
}
});
})
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
</script>



@endsection
```

thats is another view and here it works.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<head>
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Kontaktliste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Kontaktliste</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                        <a href="{{ route('contacts.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Kontakt herstellen</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-heading"><a href="{{ url('home') }}">zurück zum Senden von Nachrichten</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
           

            <div class="panel-body">
{{--                <div class="form-group">--}}
{{--                    <input type="text" class="form-controller" id="search" name="search"></input>--}}
{{--                </div>--}}
                <table id="contacts-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Vorname</th>
                        <th>Nachname</th>
                        <th>Beruf</th>
                        <th>Geburtstag</th>
                        <th>Rufnummer</th>
                        <th>Aktionen</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($contacts as $contact)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $contact->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $contact->firstName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $contact->lastName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $contact->occupation }}</td>
                            <td> {{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($contact->birthday))}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $contact->phone_number }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ route('contacts.edit', ['contact' => $contact->id]) }}">Bearbeiten</a>
                                <form action="{{ route('contacts.destroy', ['contact' => $contact->id]) }}" method="POST" style="display: inline">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-link">Löschen</button>
                                </form>
                                <a href="{{ route('home', ['contact_id' => $contact->id]) }}">Nachricht senden</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#contacts-table').DataTable();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
</script>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">


@endsection
```

someone has an idea?

i try to clear the cache ecc but doesnt work

move the end section and section content in different part,
remove it
clear cache ecc

if i remove section and extends it works, but i want to show the layout.app

thats the situation if i dont use section and layout.app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLzLS.jpg)

thats if i use them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3hRa.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you add the section? Does it give an error?

Comment: no error, but the search stop working, is so strange

Comment: If everything looks correct but the search isn't working, then I'd suggest looking at the source in the browser to make sure it all looks correct, and open your browser's developer console to see if there are any errors there on the search

Comment: TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function got this error i will see if i found why

Comment: @Lordp update your original question with that exact error message, it is your actual question. So that error ends up in a 'sub page' that extends the layout, correct? Then ask yourself if jquery is loaded. Also, figure out why you want to include the datatables .js file on  that sub-page and not in your main layout

Answer (score 0):

No, you should have something like this in layouts/app.blade.php

```html
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

and something like this in index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
@endsection
```